# How do I connect my cloud db to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, server, cloud

I'm creating an android application, and I'm hosting the database on a cloud server. I'm trying to connect these two. Also, this is my first time working with android studio.

I was told that I could use a php file to communicate between android studio and my cloud db. I was able to connect the php file to the database and verify that it works. How do I connect the php file with android studio? If you have any other suggestions besides using a php file, I'm open to hear them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You actually want to create an API using PHP. I'm assuming that you have used XAMPP and MySQL in your localhost. In the cloud server, you have to setup MySQL in your EC2 instance and configure DNS and other settings. Then, using the final url of the server, you can call the api using retrofit/okhttp libraries. I rarely work with cloud so I don't remember the specific steps. You can search about creating API using PHP in cloud and hopefully you'll find a way for your project.

Comment: @ganjaam I will look into that. Thank you!